# Set AM or PM to Date

Tags: swift

```
var dateComponents: DateComponents = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components([NSCalendar.Unit.day, NSCalendar.Unit.month, NSCalendar.Unit.year, NSCalendar.Unit.hour, NSCalendar.Unit.minute, NSCalendar.Unit.second], from: dateToFix)
dateComponents.hour = 11
dateComponents.minute = 58
dateComponents.second = 00

let fixedDate: Date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
print(fixedDate)

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: fixedDate)
print(dateString)
```

> my output : 2017-07-26 11:58 AM but i want 2017-07-26 11:58 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**change:**

```
dateComponents.hour = 11
```

**To:**

```
dateComponents.hour = 23
```

Comment: @torinopitchers that work. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed change the `dateComponents.hour` into a 24-hour value as it is expecting you to give 1-24 digits.

Documentation says:

[image]